# Get Json array from multiple table

Tags: php, json, lumen

I have two tables in my database.

```
device_category('id_category', 'name_category');
device('id_device', 'name_device', 'category_device');
```

I have a `DeviceController` with a `get()` method:

```
public function get()
{
    $devices = Device::select('*')
                 ->join('device_category','device_category.id_category','=','device.category_device')
                 ->get();

    return response()->json($devices, 200);
}
```

And the JSON result is:

```
[
    {
        "id_category": 1,
        "name_category": "Phone",
        "id_device": 1,
        "name_device": "iPhone 10"
    },
    {
        "id_category": 1,
        "name_category": "Phone",
        "id_device": 2,
        "name_device": "iPhone XS"
    },
    {
        "id_category": 2,
        "name_category": "Computer",
        "id_device": 3,
        "name_device": "Lenovo xx"
    }
]
```

Then I group the result:

```
$devices = $devices->groupBy('name_category');
return response()->json($devices, 200);
```

And got this JSON:

```
{
    "Phone" : [
        {
            "id_category": "1",
            "id_device": 1,
            "name_device": "iPhone 10"
        },
        {
            "id_category": "1",
            "id_device": 2,
            "name_device": "iPhone XS"
        }
    ],
    "Computer" : [
        {
            "id_category": "2",
            "id_device": 3,
            "name_device": "Lenovo XX"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to have an array of categories with an array of device for each categorie, how can I do it to get this result ? Can I do it in one query ? or do I need to get categories and then set devices ?

```
[
    {
        "id_category": 1,
        "name_category": "Phone",
        "device" : [
            {
                "id_device": 1,
                "id_category": 1,
                "name_device": "iPhone 10"
            },
            {
                "id_device": 2,
                "name_device": "iPhone XS"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id_category": 2,
        "name_category": "Computer",
        "device" : [
            {
                "id_device": 3,
                "name_device": "Lenovo XX"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Why don't you define relationships instead of doing a join?

Comment: I used relationship with a `HasMany` and got values using `with('relationname')`. Thats ùuch simpler! thanks

Comment: Does this resemble what you implemented @Boss? https://3v4l.org/9u4PW

Comment: @Boss please confirm my comment? I can post my advice as an answer if it is correct, but I don't have any projects where I can test my solution.

Comment: yes that is what I have done